# Powershell get specific word from textfile using -match

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have here line of code to search for specific word and output the line which this word is into.

```
Get-Content -path "C:\Apps\CamstarPerMon_logs\GetEqStatus - $getdate.log" | % {if($_ -match 'ms') {Write-Host $_}}
```

can i output specific line with specific single 'ms' word in it? because the output i get are:

```
INF: 2019-09-23 05:50:04.674 | Server1 | ID:12395msrh0000
INF: 2019-09-23 05:50:04.721 | Server1 | 47 ms
INF: 2019-09-23 05:50:05.252 | Server2 | ID:12395msrh0x9c
INF: 2019-09-23 05:50:05.346 | Server2 | 94 ms
```

because the ID also have 'ms' keyword in it.

I want an output strictly only for this:

```
INF: 2019-09-23 05:50:04.721 | Server1 | 47 ms
INF: 2019-09-23 05:50:05.346 | Server2 | 94 ms
```

is this possible for -match? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Get-Content -path "C:\Apps\CamstarPerMon_logs\GetEqStatus - $getdate.log" | % {if($_ -match '[0-9]* ms') {Write-Host $_}}
```

**EDIT:**

According to [RegExr](https://regexr.com/4lkil), the following expression matches your requirement:

`[0-9]* ms`

Thus:

`{if($_ -match '[0-9]* ms') {Write-Host $_}}`

Should match perfectly.

Comment: it works like this: % {if($_ -match "\d ms") thank you! :)